# Giving a different public IP/URL to services on different namespaces

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I'm currently running a set of pods and services inside my `production` namespace. The services are exposed via the kubernetes nginx-ingress controller.

This is working fine, all the resources can be accesed with no problems.

What I want to achieve now is to have another namespace `staging` with other types of resources and services, and also be able to access them with a public IP / url. This IP should be different from the `production` public IP since we don't want to change the URL schema on out nginx ingress.

Is there a way to achieve this using the nginx controller? We are running on AKS and installed the nginx ingress with the following helm commands:

```
# Create a namespace for your ingress resources
kubectl create namespace ingress-basic

# Add the ingress-nginx repository
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx

# Use Helm to deploy an NGINX ingress controller
helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
    --namespace ingress-basic \
    --set controller.replicaCount=2 \
    --set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux
```

as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic

This is the ingress that we use on our helm chart:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    cert-manager.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    watch-namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
#    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
#    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
    # Limit uploads to 8TB
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 800000m
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: my-cert-tls
      hosts:
        - {{ .Values.myDomain }}
  rules:
  - host: {{ .Values.myDomain }}
    http:
      paths:
      # NOTE: this one should come after all other routes. To avoid hijacking requests.
      - path: /api/svc1(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: svc1
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /api(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: svc2
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: svc3
          servicePort: 8080
  - http:
      paths:
      # NOTE: this one should come after all other routes. To avoid hijacking requests.
      - path: /api/svc2(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: svc2
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /api(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: svc1
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: svc3
          servicePort: 8080
```

Essentially I would like to see:

- IP 1 => namespace1 resources
- IP 2 => namespace2 resources

IP1 can never access namespace2 and viceversa.

Comment: it's not very clear to me, if you are just trying to have public IP and not the URL or domain for the staging?

Comment: Maybe I did not explain myself clearly enough. What I would like is to be able to have public_ip_1 => namespace1 resources only and public_ip_2 => namespace2 resources only. Then I can assign different domains to each IP but that would be after having the ingress working

Comment: I believe, the IP is assigned to the running services, not particularly to the namespace, and for different IPs, if you create a resource service type of ClusterIp, it would generate different IP for each service, no matter which namespace you are in.